# "invalid specifier" while trying to asssign a textbox value to a string

Tags: excel, textbox, vba

I am trying to assign a text box(in `workbook1`) value to a string variable(in `workbook2`). I tried this code but when i run this code i am getting a runtime error "invalid qualifier" and TextBox1 is highlighted in the line `Set Wbk1 = Workbooks.Open(TextBox1.Value)`

```
Dim Sh1 As Worksheet, Sh2 As Worksheet, Sh3 As Worksheet
Dim tmp1 As String, tmp2 As String, tmp3 As String
Dim TextBox1 As String
Dim TextBox1 As String
Dim TextBox1 As String
tmp1 = Sheets("Sheet1").TextBox1.Value
If tmp1 = "False" Then Exit Sub
tmp2 = Sheets("Sheet1").TextBox2.Value
If tmp2 = "False" Then Exit Sub
tmp3 = Sheets("Sheet1").TextBox3.Value
If tmp3 = "False" Then Exit Sub
Set Wbk1 = Workbooks.Open(TextBox1.Value)
Set Wbk2 = Workbooks.Open(TextBox2.Value)
Set Wbk3 = Workbooks.Open(TextBox3.Value)
Set Sh1 = Wbk1.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set Sh2 = Wbk2.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set Sh3 = Wbk3.Sheets("Sheet1")
```

the texboxes will have the path to the workbooks and i want that workbook in tmp1,tmp2 and tmp3 so that sh1 will be the sheet1 of the workbook selected in textbox1 and so on ..so how can i acheive that?thank you

Comment: TextBox in a Module? Or on a form? You might want to try `tmp1 = Userform1.TextBox1.Text` where `Userform1` is the userform where the textbox resides

Comment: Or is the textbox in a worksheet? And if it in a worksheet then what kind of controls is it? Form Control or ActiveX Control?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.It is a textbox in a worksheet and it is activexcontrol

Comment: Try `tmp1 = Sheets("Sheet1").TextBox1.Value`

Comment: thank you siddharth..it works well:) but now i want to put this macro in a different workbook because it is causing error when i try to open the workbook...so can you please tell me how can i refer to a textbox in workbook1 from a macro in workbook 2

Comment: One moment. Posting an asnwer

Comment: Change this `Set Wbk1 = Workbooks.Open(TextBox1.Value)` to this `Set Wbk1 = Workbooks.Open(tmp1)`.

Comment: thank you L42.what you suggested works well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the objects for the relevant workbook and the worksheet and then work with them.

For example (untested)

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim thisWb As Workbook, thatWb As Workbook
    Dim thatWs As Worksheet
    Dim tmp1

    Set thisWb = ThisWorkbook

    Set thatWb = Workbooks("Blah Blah.xlsx")
    Set thatWs = thatWb.Sheets("Sheet1")

    tmp1 = thatWs.TextBox1.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Please update your question with the relevant code. It is difficult reading code in the comments

Comment: thank you for the reply.I have updated the question.please let me know what am i doing wrong.